# How do I make an overlying rule for variable in python?

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python and I'm making a text-based RPG I want to make it so when my variable `HPX` hits `0` you die 
I currently have this:

```
if HPX == 0:
  print("YOU DIED")
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to make this application no matter what so I don't have to something like this every single time an enemy is attacking like;

```
print("The", enemy, "attacks you with its Alloy Broadsword dealing", EDDealt, "damage (damage reduced because of his clumsy swinging)")
                    HPX = HPX - EDDealt
                    if HPX <= 0:
                        print("YOU DIED")
```

Comment: Can you put the full code you wrote, to properly assess the problem and find a solution.

Comment: Make a function: `def addHPX(delta): HPX += delta; if HPX <= 0: ...`

Comment: Oof, you're starting from the very beginning here - your question is not far from "how do I write a game". But I'd recommend looking into the basics of object-oriented programming in Python - I think you'll find many useful ideas there. As for the game, what is you main game loop, so what should your game do after each action of a player? Organising that logic in a single place should help make sense of things.